# Running WSL On Windows 11, Trying to Preview Latex Document in Windows Adobe Reader from VIM in WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the WSL Subsystem on Windows and running `vim` on my WSL.
Currently I'm trying to start a Live Latex Preview with the Adobe Reader in Windows. I'm using the Live Latex Preview Plugin from the github repo
https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview.

I did my research and made some changes in `.vimrc` and came up with the following solution:

`let g:livepreview_previewer = 'explorer.exe C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe'`

When i enter the Command `:LLPStartPreview`, it wont load and `vim` just gets stuck.

EDIT: BTW, i cant start Adobe from the command line with the command

`cmd.exe start /c 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe'`

or withe the command:

`explorer.exe 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe'`

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the line in `.zshrc` and set `let g:livepreview_previewer = 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe'` in `.vimrc`?

Comment: My Bad i meant i did some changes in the ```.vimrc``` file, i tried to remove the explorer.exe, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Happens :-) I admit I'm not an expert on this. But I checked around, and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems, section **Run Windows tools from Linux** you don't need to prepend running the `.exe` with `cmd.exe` or `explorer.exe`. Neither do you need to use the full path at least on the command line. You should be able to launch `.exe`s just by giving the command. I.e. to launch notepad++ you just give command `notepad.exe`. Acrobat doesn't start this way just with command `Acrobat.exe`?

Comment: I can run notepad.exe but i cant run Acrobat.exe nor Adobe.exe.
Do you maybe know if there is a config file where i can change the environment variable ? Or you have any other ideas ?

Comment: Well there is no Adobe.exe so... :-) The starting point is figuring out how to launch Acrobat from the WSL guest CLI. I think you need to escape the space in `\Acrobat DC\`. [Howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/) has an article showing various methods - does any of those work?

Comment: So now i really edited my ```.zshrc``` to do some testing and binded start to launch adobe with the following
```alias start='/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Acrobat\ DC/Acrobat/Acrobat.exe'```
so if i enter start in my command line it starts Adobe from the CLI.
But if i add the '/mnt...' Path to the let g:livepreview_previewer it still gets stuck.

Comment: Um - so none of the Howtogeek's escape fixes worked? My first step would still be to get Acrobat launching from the shell without aliases etc. When that succeeds, I'd expect using the same exact string in `g:liveprevier_previewer` `.vimrc` -line would work as well. I think you should now edit the question to add what's been tried and what's currently there. It's a beast of a job trying to figure out current status from long comment threads :-)